# React Native Admob not working-It is showing RNGADBannerView was not found

Tags: react-native, ads

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  AsyncStorage,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  Keyboard,
  Platform
} from "react-native";
import {AdMobBanner} from 'react-native-admob';
const isAndroid = Platform.OS == "android";
const viewPadding = 10;

export default class TodoList extends Component {
  state = {
    tasks: [],
    text: "",
    
  };
  
 // componentDidMount(){
   // this.renderAdd() }
renderAdd(){
    
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <AdMobBanner
                adSize="banner"
                adUnitID="app-id"
                testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
                didFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError} />
            </View>
        );
  
}


  changeTextHandler = text => {
    this.setState({ text: text });
  };

  addTask = () => {
    let notEmpty = this.state.text.trim().length > 0;

    if (notEmpty) {
      this.setState(
        prevState => {
          let { tasks, text } = prevState;
          return {
            tasks: tasks.concat({ key: tasks.length, text: text }),
            text: ""
          };
        },
        () => Tasks.save(this.state.tasks)
      );
    }
  };

  deleteTask = i => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => {
        let tasks = prevState.tasks.slice();

        tasks.splice(i, 1);

        return { tasks: tasks };
      },
      () => Tasks.save(this.state.tasks)
    );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Keyboard.addListener(
      isAndroid ? "keyboardDidShow" : "keyboardWillShow",
      e => this.setState({ viewMargin: e.endCoordinates.height + viewPadding })
    );

    Keyboard.addListener(
      isAndroid ? "keyboardDidHide" : "keyboardWillHide",
      () => this.setState({ viewMargin: viewPadding })
    );

    Tasks.all(tasks => this.setState({ tasks: tasks || [] }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
     
      <View
        style={[styles.container, { paddingBottom: this.state.viewMargin }, {backgroundColor: "#b8b811"}]}
      >
        <AdMobBanner
                adSize="banner"
                adUnitID="ca-app-pub-6268407821278608~9156268355"
                testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
                didFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError} />
     <Text style={{backgroundColor: "yellow"}}> To-do-list </Text>
      
        <FlatList
          style={styles.list}
          data={this.state.tasks}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
            <View>
              <View style={styles.listItemCont}>
                <Text style={styles.listItem}>
                  {item.text}
                </Text>
                <Button title="Done" onPress={() => this.deleteTask(index)} />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.hr} />
            </View>}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={this.changeTextHandler}
          onSubmitEditing={this.addTask}
          value={this.state.text}
          placeholder="Add Tasks"
          returnKeyType="done"
          returnKeyLabel="done"
        />
      </View>
      
    );
  }
}

let Tasks = {
  convertToArrayOfObject(tasks, callback) {
    return callback(
      tasks ? tasks.split("||").map((task, i) => ({ key: i, text: task })) : []
    );
  },
  convertToStringWithSeparators(tasks) {
    return tasks.map(task => task.text).join("||");
  },
  all(callback) {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem("TASKS", (err, tasks) =>
      this.convertToArrayOfObject(tasks, callback)
    );
  },
  save(tasks) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("TASKS", this.convertToStringWithSeparators(tasks));
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
    padding: viewPadding,
    paddingTop: 20
  },
  list: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  listItem: {
    paddingTop: 2,
    paddingBottom: 2,
    fontSize: 18
  },
  hr: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: "gray"
  },
  listItemCont: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 40,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    borderColor: "gray",
    
    width: "100%"
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent("TodoList", () => TodoList);
```

this is my code. I am getting the following error by using react-native-admob. Its version is ^2.0.0-beta.6. I am getting an error stating that RNGADBannerVIew was not found. pls help how to tackle this error. I have even tried expo update but of no use. Thank u in advance for the one who helped.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGiJq.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually I was trying to use react-native admob however I should have used expo admob since my app was on expo not react-native

Answer (score 0):

Expo doesn't allow you to install external libraries requiring native code, which this one does. There seems to be an Expo provided package for Admob though, you can check out the docs [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/admob/)